# The model placed on gazebo is not moving with my control topics

Tags: control, gazebo, navigation, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I am following the guide descripted on [link](https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/summit_xl_sim).

I clone three repository on my catkin_ws directroy.
I did two step to run 'summit_xl_sim' like this.

```
$ cd PATH
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
$ roslaunch summit_xl_sim_bringup summit_xl_complete.launch
```

And I could see the model on Rviz and Gazebo.
Here is the log and screenshots.

```
$ roslaunch summit_xl_sim_bringup summit_xl_complete.launch
... logging to /home/msi-h310/.ros/log/859bd69e-6046-11e9-9ef6-309c23b89cf6/roslaunch-msih310-H310-Gaming-Trident3-MS-B920-18298.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://msih310-H310-Gaming-Trident3-MS-B920:34371/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_pan_position_controller/joint: summit_xl_a_front...
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_pan_position_controller/pid/d: 10.0
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_pan_position_controller/pid/i: 0.01
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_pan_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_pan_position_controller/type: velocity_controll...
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_read_state_controller/publish_rate: 100.0
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_read_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_tilt_position_controller/joint: summit_xl_a_front...
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_tilt_position_controller/pid/d: 10.0
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_tilt_position_controller/pid/i: 0.01
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_tilt_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0
 * /summit_xl_a/joint_tilt_position_controller/type: velocity_controll...
 * /summit_xl_a/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/angular/z/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/angular/z/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/angular/z/max_acceleration: 6.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/angular/z/max_velocity: 6.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/base_frame_id: summit_xl_a_base_...
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/enable_odom_tf: True
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/left_wheel: ['summit_xl_a_fro...
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/linear/x/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/linear/x/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/linear/x/max_acceleration: 6.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/linear/x/max_velocity: 3.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/linear/x/min_acceleration: -6.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/linear/x/min_velocity: -3.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/odom_frame_id: summit_xl_a_odom
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 10...
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/publish_rate: 50.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/right_wheel: ['summit_xl_a_fro...
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 10...
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/type: diff_drive_contro...
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/wheel_radius: 0.11
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/wheel_separation: 0.543
 * /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
 * /summit_xl_a/twist_mux/locks: [{'topic': 'summi...
 * /summit_xl_a/twist_mux/topics: [{'topic': 'pad_t...
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /summit_xl_a/
    controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    twist_marker (twist_mux/twist_marker)
    twist_mux (twist_mux/twist_mux)
    urdf_spawner_summit_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [18311]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 859bd69e-6046-11e9-9ef6-309c23b89cf6
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [18324]
started core service [/rosout]
process[summit_xl_a/robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [18348]
process[summit_xl_a/urdf_spawner_summit_model-3]: started with pid [18349]
process[summit_xl_a/controller_spawner-4]: started with pid [18350]
process[summit_xl_a/twist_mux-5]: started with pid [18357]
process[summit_xl_a/twist_marker-6]: started with pid [18366]
process[gazebo-7]: started with pid [18381]
process[gazebo_gui-8]: started with pid [18396]
process[rviz-9]: started with pid [18423]
[ INFO] [1555419162.975758060]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1555419162.975860355]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1555419162.976127423]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1555419162.976647928]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[INFO] [1555419162.990079, 0.000000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
SpawnModel script started
[INFO] [1555419163.239468, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter
[INFO] [1555419163.241991, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1555419164.748111, 0.000000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1555419164.791177316, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
Qt: Cannot set locale modifiers: 
[ INFO] [1555419165.448072136, 0.064000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/summit_xl_a/'
[ INFO] [1555419165.448106827, 0.064000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /summit_xl_a/)
[ INFO] [1555419165.448836843, 0.064000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = /summit_xl_a/)  <tf_prefix_>, set to "/summit_xl_a"
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
[ INFO] [1555419165.592017736, 0.064000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/summit_xl_a/'
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
[ INFO] [1555419165.595342079, 0.064000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /summit_xl_a/)  <tf_prefix_>, set to "/summit_xl_a"
[INFO] [1555419165.597384, 0.064000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
[ INFO] [1555419165.598077336, 0.064000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/summit_xl_a/'
[ INFO] [1555419165.602217472, 0.064000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /summit_xl_a/)  <tf_prefix_>, set to "/summit_xl_a"
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
[ INFO] [1555419165.610421232, 0.064000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "gazebo.msgs.Packet" because it is missing required fields: stamp, type, serialized_data
Master Unknown message type[] From[34818]
[ INFO] [1555419165.742501315, 0.086000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1555419165.764930564, 0.105000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[summit_xl_a/urdf_spawner_summit_model-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/msi-h310/.ros/log/859bd69e-6046-11e9-9ef6-309c23b89cf6/summit_xl_a-urdf_spawner_summit_model-3*.log
[WARN] [1555419193.114739, 25.727000]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[summit_xl_a/controller_spawner-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/msi-h310/.ros/log/859bd69e-6046-11e9-9ef6-309c23b89cf6/summit_xl_a-controller_spawner-4*.log
```

[image]
[image]

After this steps, I pub topics on other terminal.
But there is no any changes.

```
$ rostopic pub /summit_xl_a/robotnik_base_control/cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist "linear:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 50.0
  z: 0.0"
```

1. What is the meaning of the error on Rviz?
2. Did I miss something to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321218/the-model-placed-on-gazebo-is-not-moving-with-my-control-topics./) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2019-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/summit_xl_sim/issues/20

I fixed the problem.
After installation with `gazebo-ros-control` package.

---

Originally posted by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) with karma: 98 on 2019-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0